# Empty XML node with Notice: Trying to get property 'ref' of non-object

Tags: php, xml

```
<arrayofabc xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://www.example.com/">
  <mmmm>
    <ent>99999</ent>
    <ref>123123123</ref>
    <valor>10</valor>
    <mensagemerro>
  </mensagemerro>
</mmmm>
</arrayofabc>
```

Comment: Your XML tag is `mmmm` (four Ms), and your code is using `mmm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to user `arrayofabc` as it is no property.

Note to use `mmmm` and you don't have to use `[0]` as it is a single item:

```
echo $xmldata->mmmm->ref
```

Output

```
123123123
```

Comment: echo $xmldata->mmmm->ref returns empty

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work in mine, but I'm so tired of this, I'm giving up. Thank you for your time

Comment: @NunoNogueira Part of the problem may come from the fact that your xml has (multiple) namespaces, and xpath is better suited for dealing with that.